# Differences protractor.controlFlow().execute and browser.call()

Tags: node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, protractor

I understand that to insert a custom function into protractor control flow you can use protractor.controlFlow().execute, like the snipped below:

```js
protractor.promise.controlFlow().execute(function() {
    return getData().then(function(my_data) {
              return my_data.some_process();
     });
});
```

However, it seems I can do the same thing using the method browser.call() doing something like this:

```js
browser.call(function() {
    return getData().then(function(my_data) {
              return my_data.some_process();
     });
});
```

As far I could understand, browser.call is a wrapper to the webdriver control flow and the protractor.controlFlow() has similar functionality to protractor itself. Both returns "promises" so it seems they are doing the same thing.

Are both methods interchangeable? If not, when I should use one or the other.